# git branch doesn't output any value

Tags: git, branch, ubuntu-18.04

`git branch` doesn't output anything in any repo. This is true for repositories with one branch and ones with many branches.

I'm on Ubuntu 18 Here are some breadcrumbs, but please let me know what outputs will help:

```
$ uname -a
Linux gram-asus 4.15.0-32-generic #35-Ubuntu SMP Fri Aug 10 17:58:07 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

$ git --version
git version 2.17.1
```

Comment: Visual git clients work fine. For example, I can see all the branches using GitKraken.

Comment: Can you try `git branch -a`?

Comment: yes indeed. Same results. Er... that is to say, no results.

Comment: `git --no-pager branch -a`

Comment: Try the `--no-pager` trick. If that makes everything work, the issue is that your pager (whatever it is) is misbehaving. You can change to a different pager, or not use it at all (as with `git --no-pager ...`), or fix its behavior.

Comment: Fascinating. The `--no-pager` flag worked.

Comment: Hmmm. Okay so what setting do I use in `git config --global core.pager` to get the output back?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to torek! The solution was:

`git config --global core.pager more`